# jquery html css mouseover or hover method not working

Tags: jquery

https://codepen.io/siddharthpandestn/pen/rvMKLv

```
       ` <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".button").mouseover(function(){
           $(this).css("background-color", "white");
             }, function(){
            $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
            })
           });
        </script>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector `$(".button")` specifies all elements with `class="button"`.

If you wish to select all `button` elements, you need to use `$("button")`

Answer (score 0):

You reference the class `button` by having the `.` before it. when you are looking for the element of `button`, which does not require the `.` in front of it.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  });
  $("button").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
  });
});
```

Reference this forked [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLOoWR) to see the code in action

Answer (score 0):

Already answer given to this question, use this alternative way

```js
$(function(){    
    $("button").on({
        mouseover : function(){ $(this).css("background-color", "white"); },
        mouseleave : function(){ $(this).css("background-color", "pink"); },
    });
});
```

```css
#menu-pane {
  background-color:#48284A;
}
#menu-bar {
  padding-left:50px;
  padding-bottom:25px;
  padding-top:25px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:16px;
}

#heading {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color:#FFE1C6;
}

#menu-btn {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
}
body {
  background-color:#916C80;
}

#main-body {
  background-color:#FFF7AE;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-top:0px;
}

#p1 {
  padding-bottom:50px;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding-left:200px;
  padding-right:10px;
  font-family: 'Gugi';
  color:#48284A;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-pane">
  <div id="menu-bar" class="row">
    <div>
  <h1 id="heading">My Portfolio</h1>
      </div>  
    <div id="menu-btn" class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-7"> <button id="#btn1" style="background:transparent; color:#EDE7F6; margin-right:16px;" class="btn btn-block"> 
      About
    </button> </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-7"><button style="background:transparent; color:#EDE7F6; margin-right:16px;" class="btn btn-block">
    Portfolio
    </button> </div>
     <div class="col-xs-7"> <button style="background:transparent; color:#EDE7F6" class="btn btn-block">
      Contact
    </button> </div> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
  
<div>
  <body>
    <div id="main-body">
      <div id="body-header" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-7"><p id="p1" style="font-size:30px">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</p> </div>
<div class="col-xs-7"> <img src="https://imgur.com/CRB6iFZ"> </div> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</div>
```